# Bring from a PHP file data sent by $.ajax using Json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

As I need to bring separate data from a php file, and create an HTML piece to be injected with jQuery, I've choosen Json.

I send it from my PHP main file (between script tags) like this:

```
$.ajax({dataType: "json", url:'course_generator.php', data:{co_subj_co:editedCourseId}}).done(function(newCourse){
    var newCourseStructure = '<div class="tableRow dynamicRow noHeight injectedRow" data-isMultisubjectValue="'+isMultisubjectValue+'" data-subjectsNum="'+subjectsNum+'" data-id="'+courseId+'" id="'+courseId+'" data-abbrev="'+newCourseAbbrev+'" data-courseTypeId="'+newCourseTypeId+'" title="'+newCourseName+'"><div class="contentColumn40"><span class="tableContentText">'+newCourseName+' ('+newCourseTypeName+')</span></div><div class="contentColumn40">'+subjectList+'</div><div class="contentColumn10"><div class="tableIconLink"><a href="#"><div class="editIcon" data-id="'+courseId+'" title="Editar '+newCourseName+'"></div></a></div></div><div class="contentColumn10"><div class="tableIconLink"><a href="#"><div data-id="'+courseId+'" class="discontinueIcon" title="Discontinuar '+newCourseName+'"></div></a></div></div></div>';}
```

This sends properly `editedCourseId` value. And what's inside `course_generator.php` is:

```
$courseId = $_POST['co_subj_co'];

$select_co = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM course_conf JOIN course_type ON co_fk_ct_id=ct_id JOIN co_rel_subj ON co_subj_co='$courseId' JOIN subject_conf ON su_id=co_subj_subj WHERE co_id='$courseId'");
$result_co = mysql_fetch_array($select_co);

$newCourseId = $result_co['co_id'];
$newCourseName = $result_co['co_name'];
$newCourseAbbrev = $result_co['co_abbrev'];
$newCourseTypeId = $result_co['co_fk_ct_id'];
$newCourseTypeName = $result_co['ct_name'];
$isMultisubjectValue = $result_co['co_multisubject'];

$newCourseValues = '{"newCourseId":'.$newCourseId.',"newCourseName":'.$newCourseName.',"newCourseAbbrev":'.$newCourseAbbrev.',"newCourseTypeId":'.$newCourseTypeId.',"newCourseTypeName":'.$newCourseTypeName.',"isMultisubjectValue":'.$isMultisubjectValue.'}';
```

I am afraid Im not receiving it properly by `$courseId = $_POST['co_subj_co'];`, and neither `$newCourseValues` are being received properly on my main PHP file as my `newCourseStructure` is not generating anything. Could you please identify the several errors I am sure I'm making? Thank you.

---

UPDATE:

After changing my PHP main file to:

```
$.ajax({type : 'POST', dataType: "json", url:'config/forms/course_conf/course_generator.php', data:{co_subj_co:editedCourseId}}).done(function(newCourse){
var courseId = newCourse.newCourseId;
var newcourseName = newCourse.newCourseName;
var isMultisubjectValue = newCourse.isMultisubjectValue;
var subjectsNum = newCourse.subjectsNum;
var newCourseAbbrev = newCourse.newCourseAbbrev;
var newCourseTypeId = newCourse.newCourseTypeId;
var newCourseTypeName = newCourse.newCourseTypeName;
var newCourseStructure = '<div class="tableRow dynamicRow noHeight injectedRow" data-isMultisubjectValue="'+isMultisubjectValue+'" data-subjectsNum="'+subjectsNum+'" data-id="'+courseId+'" id="'+courseId+'" data-abbrev="'+newCourseAbbrev+'" data-courseTypeId="'+newCourseTypeId+'" title="'+newCourseName+'"><div class="contentColumn40"><span class="tableContentText">'+newCourseName+' ('+newCourseTypeName+')</span></div><div class="contentColumn40">'+subjectList+'</div><div class="contentColumn10"><div class="tableIconLink"><a href="#"><div class="editIcon" data-id="'+courseId+'" title="Editar '+newCourseName+'"></div></a></div></div><div class="contentColumn10"><div class="tableIconLink"><a href="#"><div data-id="'+courseId+'" class="discontinueIcon" title="Discontinuar '+newCourseName+'"></div></a></div></div></div>';}
```

And my course_generator.php file to:

```
$courseId = intval($_POST['co_subj_co']);
$subjectList = "";
$data ="";

$select_co = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM course_conf JOIN course_type ON co_fk_ct_id=ct_id JOIN co_rel_subj ON co_subj_co='$courseId' JOIN subject_conf ON su_id=co_subj_subj WHERE co_id='$courseId'");
$result_co = mysql_fetch_array($select_co);

$outArr['newCourseId'] = $result_co['co_id'];
$outArr['newCourseName'] = $result_co['co_name'];
$outArr['newCourseAbbrev'] = $result_co['co_abbrev'];
$outArr['newCourseTypeId'] = $result_co['co_fk_ct_id'];
$outArr['newCourseTypeName'] = $result_co['ct_name'];
$outArr['isMultisubjectValue'] = $result_co['co_multisubject'];

$subjectsNum=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM co_rel_subj WHERE co_subj_co = '$courseId'"));

$outArr['subjectsNum'] = $subjectsNum;
echo json_encode($outArr);
```

Instead of showing the HTML piece structured, this is what `$newCourseStructure`  results:

```
{"newCourseId":"243","newCourseName":"a","newCourseAbbrev":"ae","newCourseTypeId":"1","newCourseTypeName":"M\u00e1ster","isMultisubjectValue":"1","subjectList":"
Edici\u00f3n y Acabado de Imagen Digital<\/div>
","subjectsNum":1}
```

Comment: are you sure the `editedCourseId` variable is defined in your jquery script before you actually do the ajax call?

Comment: You say below that "nothing displays".  What are you doing with `newCourseStructure` after it's generated?

Comment: I've added an update with actual status of my problem. I guess Im making sthing wrong with newCourseStructure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have annotated two things in the code:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST', 
    dataType: "json", 
    url:'config/forms/course_conf/course_generator.php',
    data:{
        co_subj_co:editedCourseId
    }})
    .done(function(newCourse){
        var courseId = newCourse.newCourseId;
        var newcourseName = newCourse.newCourseName;
        var isMultisubjectValue = newCourse.isMultisubjectValue;
        var subjectsNum = newCourse.subjectsNum;
        var newCourseAbbrev = newCourse.newCourseAbbrev;
        var newCourseTypeId = newCourse.newCourseTypeId;
        var newCourseTypeName = newCourse.newCourseTypeName;
        var newCourseStructure = '<div class="tableRow dynamicRow noHeight injectedRow"'
        + ' data-isMultisubjectValue="' + isMultisubjectValue + '"'
        + ' data-subjectsNum="' + subjectsNum + '"'
        + ' data-id="' + courseId + '"'
        + ' id="' + courseId + '"'
        + ' data-abbrev="' + newCourseAbbrev + '"'
        + ' data-courseTypeId="' + newCourseTypeId + '"'
        + ' title="' + newCourseName + '">'
        + '<div class="contentColumn40"><span class="tableContentText">'
        + newCourseName + ' (' + newCourseTypeName + ')</span></div>'
        // WHERE IS subjectList DEFINED?
        + '<div class="contentColumn40">' + subjectList 
        + '</div>'
        + '<div class="contentColumn10"><div class="tableIconLink">'
        + '<a href="#"><div class="editIcon" data-id="' + courseId + '"'
        + ' title="Editar ' + newCourseName + '"></div>'
        + '</a></div></div><div class="contentColumn10"><div class="tableIconLink">'
        + '<a href="#"><div data-id="'+courseId+'" class="discontinueIcon" '
        + 'title="Discontinuar '+newCourseName+'"></div></a></div></div></div>';
    /*
     * your HTML is generated, but you never put it in the DOM
     */
    $('#idOutputWrapper').empty().html(newCourseStructure);
}
```

When you use subjectList from the json response, please notice that it comes with a closing `</div>` tag for some reason, maybe you should change that, too.

btw: Your code formatting is horrible, sorry to say so. You can compress your js before uploading it to the server, but while working on it, it NEEDS to be readable. I just edited it to fit better in the codeblock here.

Comment: Thank you Armin, totally right on how hard its to read. Im about to apply those changes, i'll tick if works. Very grateful.

Comment: Hi, glad to hear it worked and thanks for accepting the answer, not all do.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON string is not valid JSON because you don't use quotes around the string values. Instead of manually creating JSON, create an array or object and then `json_encode()` it.

You don't apper to output the JSON string. Use `echo` or `print`.

Add `dataType : 'json'` to your ajax request so that jQuery will parse the JSON, returning the native JavaScript object. All of the variables you use in the success function are `undefined`. After parsing the JSON you should use

```
var courseId = newCourse.newCourseId; // and so on
```

Your ajax request doesn't have a type and so will default to GET. add `type : 'POST'` if you want to use POST.

Comment: Im about to apply these changes. I'll tell then, thank you for your attention.

Comment: I've added an update with actual status of my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$_GET['co_subj_co'];` instead of `POST`.

As long as you don't specify the method to jQuery's ajax call, it's made by GET, not POST.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually using POST, or are you firing off a GET request (your browser's developer tools should tell you this easily). You should also make sure that `$courseId` is an integer by `$courseId = intval($_POST['co_cubj_co']);`. In addition, you should add a condition for the event that the requested ID is not found.

Comment: Thank you. I've corrected that. There must be more errors as still nothing displays.

Answer (score 1):

As MueR suggests, the reason to make sure that courseID is an integer is to prevent SQL injection (unless you want people to do things like delete your entire DB at will).  This, of course, assumes that courseID is something like an autoincrement int.

However, you've got a number of other problems.  Your JSON is invalid since you're ostensibly writing out unquoted strings... you should just use json_encode:

```
$outArr = array();
$outArr['newCourseId'] = $result_co['co_id'];
$outArr['newCourseName'] = $result_co['co_name'];
...
echo json_encode($outArr);
```

Personally, I prefer to just use $_REQUEST, which concatenates both $_POST and $_GET.  Makes it easier.

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOO! Do not use $_REQUEST (which combines GET, POST and COOKIE fyi). Validate where your input comes from. If you expect POST variables, get them from POST. While $_REQUEST makes it nicer for _you_ to debug, it's unsafe.

Comment: Yes, always validate -- But there's nothing extra-unsafe about it.  Any user-derived string is subject to attack, so there's NO REASON to worry about GET vs. POST vs. COOKIE per se.

Comment: This was really useful. Thank you vey much for your attention

Comment: I've added an update with actual status of my problem. Thank you.